# Log4Net section in Web.Config generates Error

Tags: c#-4.0, log4net, log4net-configuration

So I am trying to set up Log4Net in my Web .NET 4.0 application.  I have added the correct .dll to my project and have appended the following to my Web.Config file as starters:

```xml
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
</configSections>
 <log4net debug="true">
 <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\\TestProj\\TestLog.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
```

However, if I append the "log4net" section to Web.Config, I will receive the error message

> Unable to start debugging on the web server.  See help for common
>   configuration problems.....
>
> Make sure the server is running correctly.  Verify there are no syntax
>   errors in the web.config........

**NOTE**
I can remove all the internals of this section and leave only the declaration:

```xml
<log4net></log4net>
```

and I will still get the same error.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to track down this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at a sample configurations at [log4net documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) homepage.
Chances are you've misplaced required tags.

Answer (score 16):

For developers who are not sure exactly how to get started following might be a help

**ConfigSections in app.config**

Remember to tell your application that a library is introducing a custom configuration section are you are intended to utilize, I am not perfectly sure if it is mandatory or not but I always use it as first section within root `<configuration>` tag.

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
```

**log4net config in app.config**

There are quite a variety of different appenders available in log4net but I usually use RollingFileAppender so I am using the same one in this sample, you can find rest of those [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

```xml
<log4net>
    <!-- file appender -->
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:/logs/my_log_file.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>
      <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

**Update AssemblyInfo.cs file**

I always miss this step whenever I have to create a new project. So remember you have to tell your application to watch for `XMLConfigurator` to perform configuration of log4net, so following line goes at the end of AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

**Get Started**

Remember to include the reference of [log4net.dll](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi)  then use following line of code to initialize logger within a class

```
private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
```

And at the end lets use it like following

```
log.Info("Hello log4net");
```

Happy Logging :)