# Log4Net configuration to log into DB : Nothing happens

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm trying to use `log4net` for the first time to log into my DB.

Following [this simple tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284263/2687153), nothing happens. No crash, but nothing is logged into my DB.

Here is what I did after installing `log4net` with Nuget :

**Web.config**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    ...
</configSections>
```

Then I just copy / paste the sample of the documentation, just replacing my connection string (which is working)

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <!--send all logs to appenders-->
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=MYSERVER;initial catalog=MYDB;integrated security=false;persist security info=True" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

Yes there is no UserId / password, this is my debug session on my localhost. This is not a problem.

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

**Then, in a Random Controller, just for test**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HomeController));

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        logger.Error("My first log");
        return View();
    }
}
```

And my DB is desperately empty !

Can someone point me out where I'm wrong ? I probably miss something obvious...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you create the `[Log]` table in your database, and does it have all of the columns listed in the `INSERT` statement found in the web config?  Are the columns typed correctly?

Comment: Absolutely, I used the CREATE TABLE statement given in the offical doc : https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html (I'm using SQLServer)

Comment: When using the assembly attribute to do configuration, the attribute is read by the first line of code that triggers a logging statement.  The first logging statement will then scan whatever assembly it lives in, looking for the attribute.  If you have some third-party code that also uses log4net, it may be trying to configure itself before your statement in the controller, in which case it will scan the third-party assembly and not yours.  Try putting a logging statement in Application_Start and see if that helps.

Comment: Just for testing, can you try if log4net logs errors into a text file?

Comment: @ChrisNielsen I tried to log at the very first line of my Application_Start : it's the same, nothing happens... I have no other third-party code yet (except EF), this is a quite new project

Comment: @Ignas I followed the appender described in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284263/2687153
Nothing happens neither :-(

Comment: Does that connection string work?

Comment: To follow up in Ignas's approach, I notice the rolling file appender you linked to writes to `C:/logs/my_log_file.log`.  Are you sure your code has permission to write to that?  If you do `File.Create("C:/logs/test.log").Dispose();` does it create the file where you expect it to, or do you get a permissions error?

Comment: @ChrisNielsen Well spotted, I haven't permission... So the file appender works if I specify a location where I have permission, thanks a lot (and thanks to Ignas too !) But that doesn't explain why the DB doesn't work. I'm sure the connectionString is OK, whereas it looks like it doesn't...

Comment: How have you proven that the connection string works?  That `integrated security=false` without a username/password looks dodgy to me, and we are running out of other options to investigate.

Comment: @ChrisNielsen Well I must admit I'm not at ease at all with connectionStrings... Actually I created a `.udl` file, enter the parameters, verify that the connection is OK, then I opened it in Notepad and get my string... Ok this is probably not at all the best way, but I'm more than open to learn a best way

Comment: Ok I'm a newbie... I just did it again and the connectionstring generated was : `data source=MYPC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDB;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False"`
And it works... :facepalm:
So if you have a better way to get a connectionString, or want to put it as an answer, i'll accept it with pleasure !

Comment: I imagine most people are ill at ease with connection strings.  Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks again for pointing me out the right direction ! :-)